# Go to a specified line in a text file and store it into SQL server

Tags: c#, split

This is my text file.

```
****enter code here****
#          version : 1.0
#           FoR UID : 1.2.840.113704.1.111.2564.1221141496.5

#
#              name : POI4
#      instance UID : 1.3.46.670589.5.2.10.2.4.46.678.1.3676.1389367479027
#       description : 
#        created by : CODE1\ing07445
#                on : 01/10/2014 09:54:39
#             color : FF00FFFF
#       slice index : 0
 -0.58593750,36.63890457,-832.68395996

End Grafics
```

---

I want to convert this into database.  I want to go this line `-0.58593750,36.63890457,-832.68395996`
 and store it in SQL server by giving a name "Value" .

How can i do it in C#??

Comment: Does that line always on the same row or is there something else that you can use to always identify that line?

Comment: @SimonBelanger-i tried inserting all those values into SQL server .. i did this in console , now need to providde a good GUI for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple actually, consider this:

```
var line = File.ReadAllLines("filepath")
               .Where(line => !line.StartsWith("#"))
               .First();
```

store it in SQL server part is up to you